# How do I write a program that duplicates a row when multiple values in one column are assigned to a single value in another?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables:

table1:

| MODULE | EMPLOYEE |
| --- | --- |
| A | Billy Bob |
| A | Billy Joe |
| B | John Doe |
| B | Jane Doe |
| C | Catey Rice |

table2: Primary_Key = (MATERIAL_ID, MATERIAL_NUM)

| MATERIAL_ID | MATERIAL_NUM | MODULE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111111 | 222222222222 | A |
| 11111111112 | 222222222223 | B |
| 11111111113 | 222222222224 | C |

and I need a query that will fill in my third table so that it looks like this:

table3: Foreign_Key = (MATERIAL_ID, MATERIAL_NUM)

| MATERIAL_ID | MATERIAL_NUM | EMPLOYEE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111111 | 222222222222 | Billy Bob |
| 11111111111 | 222222222222 | Billy Joe |
| 11111111112 | 222222222223 | John Doe |
| 11111111112 | 222222222223 | Jane Doe |
| 11111111113 | 222222222224 | Catey Rice |

I tried this query:

```
INSERT INTO table3(EMPLOYEE)
SELECT t1.EMPLOYEE
  FROM table1 t1
  FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
             ON t1.MODULE = t2.MODULE;
```

I already have `MATERIAL_ID` and `MATERIAL_NUM` filled in on `table3` by inserting the data from `table2`. If I need to do it over with `EMPLOYEE` in the query I'll just empty the table and rewrite it.

The issue I am running into is this error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MATERIAL_ID"),
which I figure is happening because I don't have a method that duplicates the rows as multiple
names fill out the same `MATERIAL_ID` and `MATERIAL_NUM`. So I need help to create the method to
do that.

Comment: It sounds like you're making more work for yourself than you need. Table 3 doesn't seem to need to exist at all - it's just the result of joining tables 1 and 2, but with the added opportunity of being inconsistent with them.

Comment: Are values in `table2.MODULE` unique? If not, then full joining by it may cause troubles

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I  created table3 so that there is direct correlation between the material and the employee who is responsible for it. It will also be used for a material claiming tool where employees can directly select the material by it's id/number.

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov modules are not unique, but I'm not sure how else to join the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to `UPDATE` the employee column, not `INSERT` new rows:

```
update table3 t3
    set employee = (select t1.employee
                    from table1 t1 join
                         table2 t2
                         on t2.module = t1.module
                    where t3.materialid = t2.materialid
                   );
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at `table3` after update. It's saying partially recognized rules...

Comment: @TheSchmidly . . . That is the `update` syntax.  Of course, you need to put in your actual table name.  The syntax works just fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3b8fed6848f514bfb1ba110899579c8f.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong then, I'll keep investigating. Maybe I'm missing something. That website is nice btw so thanks for sharing it.

Comment: I figured it out I was typing update table table3 instead of update table3 lol